# Get headlines from web archive

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get headline from `www.bbc.co.uk/news`. The code I have works fine and it is as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urllib2
import re

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news'
soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(url), "lxml")

titleTag = soup.html.head.title

print(titleTag.string)

titles = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'title-link__title-text'})

headlines = [t.text for t in titles]

print(headlines)
```

But I would like to build a dataset from a given date, let's say 1st April 2016. But the headlines keep on changing during the day and BBC does not keep the history.

So I thought to get it from `web archive`. For example, I would like to get headlines from this [url](http://web.archive.org/web/20160203074646/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news) (`http://web.archive.org/web/20160203074646/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news`) for the timestamp `20160203074646`.

When I paste the url in my code, the output contains the headlines.

**EDIT**

But how do I automate this process for all the timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

To see all snapshots for a given URL, replace the timestamp with an asterisk:

> http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.bbc.co.uk

then screen scrape that.

A few things to consider:

- The [Wayback API](https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php) will give you the nearest single snapshot to a given timestamp.  You seem like you want all available snapshots, which is why I suggested screen scraping.
- The BBC might change headlines faster than the Wayback Machine can snapshot them.
- The BBC provides [RSS feeds](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/help/rss/default.stm) which can be [parsed](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) more reliably.  There is a listing under "Choose a Feed".

EDIT: have a look at the `feedparser` [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/common-rss-elements.html)

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk')
d.entries[0]
```

Output

```
{'guidislink': False,
 'href': u'',
 'id': u'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-37003819',
 'link': u'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-37003819',
 'links': [{'href': u'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-37003819',
            'rel': u'alternate',
            'type': u'text/html'}],
 'media_thumbnail': [{'height': u'432',
                      'url': u'http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A34/production/_90704367_mediaitem90704366.jpg',
                      'width': u'768'}],
 'published': u'Sun, 07 Aug 2016 21:24:36 GMT',
 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=21, tm_min=24, tm_sec=36, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=220, tm_isdst=0),
 'summary': u"Turkey's President Erdogan tells a huge rally in Istanbul that he would approve the return of the death penalty if it was backed by parliament and the public.",
 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk',
                    'language': None,
                    'type': u'text/html',
                    'value': u"Turkey's President Erdogan tells a huge rally in Istanbul that he would approve the return of the death penalty if it was backed by parliament and the public."},
 'title': u'Turkey death penalty: Erdogan backs return at Istanbul rally',
 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk',
                  'language': None,
                  'type': u'text/plain',
                  'value': u'Turkey death penalty: Erdogan backs return at Istanbul rally'}}
```

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, can you please tell me how can I do it from the feeds?